# Create go structure to accept json with anonymous top level items

Tags: arrays, go, struct

I am receiving this structure and do not know how to create the go structure to marshal it into:

[
{
"searchinfo": [
{
"PrefProv": "68",
"Language": "Uzbek"
}
]
}
]

How do I define the go structure to unMarshal it into?

Comment: Thank you, that helped and gave me a start.

Comment: Its a JSON array so you start by unmarshaling it into a slice, not a struct.

Comment: That also helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type RawStruct []struct {
    Searchinfo []struct {
        PrefProv string `json:"PrefProv"`
        Language string `json:"Language"`
    } `json:"searchinfo"`
}

func main() {
    raw_data := `[{"searchinfo":[{"PrefProv":"68","Language":"Uzbek"}]}]`
    var rawStruct RawStruct
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(raw_data), &rawStruct); err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", rawStruct)
    fmt.Println("---------")
    for indexStruct, itemStruct := range rawStruct {
        fmt.Printf("Iterating element [%d] of itemStruct: [%+v]\n", indexStruct, itemStruct)
        for indexInfo, itemInfo := range itemStruct.Searchinfo {
            fmt.Printf("[%d] PrefProv: %s\n", indexInfo, itemInfo.PrefProv)
            fmt.Printf("[%d] Language: %s\n", indexInfo, itemInfo.Language)
        }
    }
}
```

---

Result:

```
[{Searchinfo:[{PrefProv:68 Language:Uzbek}]}]
---------
Iterating element [0] of itemStruct: [{Searchinfo:[{PrefProv:68 Language:Uzbek}]}]
[0] PrefProv: 68
[0] Language: Uzbek
```